# Bootstrap 2.1.1 Website Issue - Thumbnail Image Blue Glow On Chrome Mobile

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap-2

I just recently updated my Chrome app on my Galaxy S3. Now my personal website that I created using a bootstrap 2.1.1 template is having a strange issue in my portfolio. When I select an image to go full screen, the thumbnail highlights blue, but overlaps the full size image.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I've tried every other web browser, even the desktop Chrome version and everything looks fine. Again, this started after i updated my Chrome browser on my galaxy s3.

The links below show screenshots of my galaxy s3 in portrait and landscape so you can understand the issue better.

Links:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wpX2.png#1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wpX2.png

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Try updating to Bootstrap v2.3.2. Note that Bootstrap v2 is no longer maintained, so you might want to consider scrapping that template entirely and finding one that's compatible with Bootstrap v3 (current version).

Comment: ok. that's what i was afraid of. Thanks